# Relógio em Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Criei um relógio em `Action Script` para usar como conteúdo para **Digital Signage** com o horário de 6 países, mas estou com um problema com o horário de verão.

Usei o getHours para pegar os horários e apliquei a diferença do fuso com matemática simples, mas o gethours pega o horário do sistema.

Como posso fazer para pegar um horário online ou de cada pais separado ou pelo menos um horário sem fuso nenhum e trabalhar melhor o horário de verão ? Tem algum lugar onde eu possa pegar horário online ou até mesmo criar algo no meu servidor para fazer isso ?

Comment: Este site pode te ajudar: http://www.horacerta.com.br/, possui o horário de diversos países, talvez possa utilizar como fonte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu Flash estiver em um sistema com conexão a internet você pode consumir esta API -> http://timezonedb.com/api ela permite você obter o tempo de qualquer lugar do mundo (esteja normal ou em horário de verão) além de escolher o formato de resposta (entre XML ou JSON).

Estou considerando que você tem internet baseado na forma como você deve distribuir conteúdo para o digital signage.

Caso não tenha ai seria o caso de pedir via rede ou de configurar de acordo com o relógio da maquina em um arquivo externo.

Comment: Putz era exatamente isso que eu precisava, eu estava fazendo com o relógio da maquina. Obrigado.